# PHP Dependency Injection - Pimple, etc.. - Why use associative arrays vs getters?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

We're looking at integrating a Dependency Injection Container into our project. Every DIC I've looked at uses associative arrays and/or magic methods. For example, here's a sample from the Pimple page:

```
$container['session_storage'] = function ($c) {
    return new $c['session_storage_class']($c['cookie_name']);
};

$container['session'] = function ($c) {
    return new Session($c['session_storage']);
};
```

Is there a reason for this? I hate having strings in my code as anything other than a literal string that's going to be displayed somewhere. You lose so much of the power of the IDE (which makes the code harder to maintain, something we're trying to avoid!).

My preference would be something more like:

```
class Container {

    function getSessionStorage()
    {
        return new $this->getSessionStorageClass($this->getCookieName);
    }

    function getSession()
    {
        return new Session($this->getSessionStorage());
    }

}
```

Is there a reason not to do this? Am I missing some magic of Pimple that won't work if we go this route?

Comment: Your preference is basically a handwritten DIC. Pimple and others use arrays (or similar techniques) to allow configurablity without rewriting the container.

Comment: Maybe there's something I'm still not getting, but I still don't see much benefit to Pimple's approach. The container still has to be configured somewhere. There's a pretty comparable amount of code in both examples. Does anyone have an example showing "in Pimple I'd do this" (nice simple bit of code), "but you're way I'd have to do this" (que huge unwieldily monster). 

I'm new to the concept of using a DiC so I am assuming there is something I'm missing, I'm just trying to understand what.

Comment: A good example would be if you were loading the dependency map from a config. Hard-coding the methods simply wouldn't be an option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "magic" of the `ArrayAccess` extension in Pimple is that it's completely reusable and *interoperable*. One of the big features of Pimple as a DIC is that a defined service can make use of previously defined services and/or parameters. Let's say (for whatever reason) you had a `Session` object that required a `Filter` instance. Without a DIC you could write:

```
$session = new Session(new Filter);
```

With pimple you could write:

```
$pimple['filter'] = function($c) {
    return new Filter;
};
$pimple['session'] = function($c) {
    return new Session($c['filter']);
}
```

Pimple uses the previously registered 'Filter' service in the instantiation of the Session object. This benefit is **not unique** to a DIC that implements `ArrayAccess`, but the reusability is very useful for code reuse and sharing. You certainly can hard-code getters/setters for certain services, or all of them, but the benefit of reusability is all but lost.

The other option is to use magic methods as getters/setters. This will give the DIC an API more like what you want in your code, and you could even use them as a wrapper over the Pimple `ArrayAccess` code (though you might be better off writing a purpose-built DIC at that point).  Wrapping over Pimple's existing methods could look something like this:

```
public function __call($method, $args) {
    if("set" === substr($method, 0, 3)) {
        return $this[substr($method, 3)];
    }
    if("get" === substr($method, 0, 3) && isset($args[0])) {
        return $this[substr($method, 3)] = $args[0];
    }
    return null;
}
```

You could also use `__set` and `__get` to give object-like access to the services & params in the DIC, like this: (still wrapping over Pimple's `ArrayAccess` methods)

```
public function __set($key, $value) {
    return $this[$key] = $value;
}

public function __get($key) {
    return $this[$key];
}
```

Beyond that you could rewrite the DIC entirely to use magic methods exclusively, and have an object-like API syntax instead of implementing `ArrayAccess`, but that should be fairly easy to figure out :]

Answer (score 7):

You care about IDE autocompletion because you are going to use your container as a **Service locator**, i.e. you are going to call your container.

You shouldn't do that ideally. The service locator pattern is an anti-pattern: instead of injecting the dependencies you need (dependency injection), you fetch them from the container. That means that **your code is coupled to the container**.

Pimple (and its array access) doesn't really solve that, so I'm not directly answering your question, but I hope it's making it clearer.

---

Side note: what's the "ideal" way? Dependency injection.

Never use or call the container, except at the root of your application (for example to create the controllers). Always inject the objects you need (the dependencies), instead of injecting the whole container.

Comment: The container is a single dependency. Everything else you can swap out. Is that really so terrible?

Comment: @Mark Something I left out but is really important too: using the container hides the dependencies. Instead of explicit and strong dependencies (e.g. as constructor parameters) you end up will unclear (potentially infinite) dependencies because you access them through the container.

Comment: That's a very good practice. We should never rely on hardcoded dependency names like 'filter'... we should, like you said, let the Container inject the required instances automatically (and forget about using array keys), and that's what Pimple does not do.

For being able to do so, dependencies should always be instances of some class (never scalars or arrays), and should be explicitly type-hinted in constructors and class methods.

I don't know right now which library is able to do so, but I think that there is some of them like Aura.DI (which also has good performance) .

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli I also considered using your library in my company. thanks for the amazing job behind

Answer (score 1):

Pimple is designed to be accessed like an array (it implements the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface).  If you want a method-like interface instead, simply extend Pimple and use the [`__call()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method:

```
class Zit extends Pimple
{
    public function __call($method, array $args)
    {
        $prefix = substr($method, 0, 3);
        $suffix = isset($method[3])
                ? substr($method, 3)
                : NULL;

        if ($prefix === 'get') {
            return $this[$suffix];
        } elseif ($prefix === 'set') {
            $this[$suffix] = isset($args[0])
                           ? $args[0]
                           : NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$zit = new Zit();

// equivalent to $zit['Foo'] = ...
$zit->setFoo(function() {
    return new Foo();
});

// equivalent to ... = $zit['Foo']
$foo = $zit->getFoo();
```

As for why Pimple doesn't come with this functionality out of the box, I have no idea.  Probably just to keep it as simple as possible.

---

**Edit:**

Concerning IDE autocompletes, they also won't be available with magic methods like this.  Some editors allow you to give doc-block hints to make up for this, using `@property` and `@method`, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want hi-performance and keep configurability, the only option is to generate DI container code.

The simple option is to prepare methods you will need and write a generator. Something like this (untested code, for inspiration only):

```
$config_file = 'config.ini';
$di_file = 'var/di.php';
if (mtime($config_file) > mtime($di_file) // check if config changed
    || mtime(__FILE__) > mtime($di_file)  // check if generator changed
{ 
    $config = parse_ini_file($config_file, true); // get DI configuration
    ob_start(); // or use fopen($di_file) instead
    echo "<", "?php\n",
        "class DIContainer {\n";
    foreach ($config_file as $service_name => $service) {
        // generate methods you want, use configuration in $service as much as possible
        echo "function create", $service_name, "() {\n",
             "  return new ", $service['class'], "();\n\n";
    }
    echo "}\n";
    file_put_contents($di_file, ob_get_contents());
    ob_end_clean();
}

require($di_file);
$dic = new DIContainer();
```

Usage:

```
$service = $dic->createSomeService();
// Now you have instance of FooBar when example config is used
```

Example config file:

```
[SomeService]
class = "FooBar"

[OtherService]
class = "Dummy"
```

Answer (score 0):

We ended up going with a hybrid of the two approaches.

Inside the dic Pimple manages things, externally objects are retrieved via getters.

e.g.

```
abstract class DicAbstract {

    /**
     * @var \Pimple
     */
    protected $_dic;

    /**
     * Initialise the pimple container
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_dic = new \Pimple();

        $this->defineContainer();
    }

    /**
     * Define dependency items
     */
    protected abstract function defineContainer();
}
```

---

```
class Dic extends DicAbstract {

    /**
     * @return \Component\Error\Manager
     */
    public function errorManager()
    {
        return $this->_dic['errorManager'];
    }

    /**
     * @return SomethingElse
     */
    public function somethingElse()
    {
        return $this->_dic['somethingElse'];
    }

    /**
     * Define the container
     */
    protected function defineContainer()
    {
        $this->_dic['errorTypesGeneral'] = function() {
            return new \Component\Error\Type\General();
        };

        $this->_dic['errorTypesSecurity'] = function() {
            return new \Component\Error\Type\Security();
        };

        $this->_dic['errorManager'] = function($dic) {
            $errorManager = new \Component\Error\Manager();

            $errorManager->registerMessages($dic['errorTypesGeneral']);
            $errorManager->registerMessages($dic['errorTypesSecurity']);

            return $errorManager;
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: So instead of DI, you went with factory pattern, solid choice. The only problem is, you are returning varying objects, which makes it harder on the calling code, unless you use an interface to make sure each object share the same public accessors.